# How to access a member of an incomplete type in C programming

Tags: c

Assume I have the following incomplete type declared in my `child.h` file

```
typedef struct child * child_ptr;
```

and I have the the <s>incomplete</s> complete type definition in my `child.c` file

```
struct child {
   char * type;
   int age;
};
```

Assume this is my `main.c` file

```
// some code before the main 
int main( void ) {
   struct child *child = new_child( "Boy", 5 );
   child->type;  // i know i will get an error
}
```

Unlike C++, Java, C#, C has only limited support for encapsulating types. The only tool that C gives for encapsulation is incomplete types. These are types that describe objects but lack information needed to determine their sizes. This is the reason why I will get an error after compiling my program. So, is there a way to access them?

One way of doing this, I think, is by having "public" functions declared in my `child.h` file. For instance, a function that takes a pointer to a child object and returns the value stored in the "type" member variable; however, this would prevent data hiding. If I move the struct to the `child.h` file, all the members will be by default public. Again, this will prevent data hiding.

Comment: You can achieve encapsulation by implementing getter/setter functions in child.c. That way your struct can remain opaque.

Comment: *one way of doing this, is by having "public" functions declared in my child.h file.* <-- Yes, and no it does not prevent data hiding, it permits it.

Comment: the new_child is a function, sort of like a constructor, that initializes a child object based on the argument passed to it.

Comment: @Joe yes but wouldn't that prevent data hiding?

Comment: *" is by having "public" functions declared in my child.h file."* ... *"however, this would prevent data hiding"* So you want outside access or not?

Comment: In C, you have to make a decision: are consumers of the type allowed to see the interstices of the type.  If the answer's "Yes", then you make the type information available; if the answer's "No", you don't.  You then abide by the consequences of the decision.  If you don't like it, change languages to something that supports the abstractions you want — C doesn't provide them.  At least with getter/setter functions (which an 'answer' that should be in the question says you don't want) you can control the access.

Answer (score 2):

You could create function prototypes in the `child.h` file, which get `struct child*` as parameter and return different members.

For example:

```
char * get_name(child_ptr chld);
```

In the `child.c` file, where the definition of `struct child` is visible, and use it in the `main.c` file like so:

```
child_ptr chld = new_child( "Boy", 5 );
char* child_name = get_name(chld);
```

Answer (score 1):

In child.h provide a definition of all of the public members (and make them come first in the definition);

```
struct child{
  /*public members*/
  char private_parts[];
};
```

You don't need to provide any access to your child's private parts, and if you don't want anyone else touching them, I wouldn't. It's just there to demonstrate that there is more to the type you see here.

In child.c make another type like so:

```
struct private_child{
  struct child;
  /*private members*/
};

struct child *new_child(/*Init Params*/){
  struct private_child *tmp = malloc(sizeof *tmp);
  /* Initialize the child */
  return &tmp->child;
}

void use_child(const child *c){
  struct private_child *pc = (struct private_child *)c;
  /*access the private members*/
}
```

You can see here some examples of how to create a new child with the private_child, and how to go and access private members within child.c via a cast.
This will always work because of...

> (C1x §6.7.2.1.13: "A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its
>       initial member ... and vice versa. There may be unnamed padding within as structure
>       object, but not at its beginning.")

**Edit**

In older versions of C flexible length array members might not be available, and you can just ignore that member of the child. This array actually makes the type incomplete which you (probably) want, so that no one accidentally tries to make one of these in automatic storage (it can only be made with an allocation, and hopefully only using your specified "constructor"). I'm not sure of another way to make a type incomplete in C.

Comment: Maybe you should mention that you're creating a structure with a flexible array member.  Also notice that you are preventing someone from creating an array of `struct child`; this probably doesn't matter because the question effectively does that (but it isn't brought out elsewhere, yet).  You can have an array of pointers to an incomplete type, but you can't have an array of an incomplete type.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah this is sort of the equivalent of a "heap-only" type. There's no easy way to make that happen without forcing an incomplete type. in c++ you would achieve the same behavior by making the destructor private.

Comment: @SteveCox BINGO!! this is the answer i was looking for. I figured another way without using global accessor and mutator functions. i like your implementation. A question, when allocating memory for the pointer why not using "struct private_child" instead of "*temp". You are allocating enough memory for a pointer to a struct private_child.

Comment: @SteveCox If i were to initialize a member, an integer value, of the struct private_child, this will likely result in a crash when the program attempts to store an integer value in the pointer that the "temp" is presumably pointing to.

Comment: @SteveCox btw, how would you initialize the child?

Comment: @bforben okay there are a lot of things here. for the first one, `declaration_specifier declarator = malloc(sizeof declarator);` is a well known idiom for allocating in C, its less error prone than the alternative, since it copies the declarator which will cause a compiler error if you change it, instead of just silently erroring, and probably causing a segfault. I'm not sure why you thing initializing members of `tmp` would cause a crash. This definitely allocates enough memory.

Comment: @bforben initailizing the child from within this function is a bit cumbersome, but not too much so in my opinion: `tmp->child->member = initial_value;` or, you could make a second static initalizer function `static init_child(struct child *c);`, and call it like `init_child(&tmp->child)`. Either way is fine.

Comment: @SteveCox you declared a "struct person" inside the "struct private_child"  How can you reference to an object of that type since it is just a declaration of an incomplete type? the way i had it was "struct person *person"

Comment: @oldsport An object of which type? You should never get your hands on a pointer to the private_child, only on a pointer to the child. And the definition of a child is right there. its incomplete, but that doesn't matter, because you can still manipulate all of the members defined publicly